# Проблема с scanf в C

Tags: c, scanf

В общем, такая задача - написать программу на си, которая на входе получит число, а выведет таблицу температур:
ввод:
20
вывод:

```
\/\/\/\   °C       K      °F   
  °C      20.00  293.15   68.00
   K    -253.15   20.00 -423.67
  °F      -6.67  266.48   20.00
```

С этим проблем не возникло. Однако, во второй части задания написано, что необходимо сделать возможным ввод приказов, одник из которых T, а второй C.
Приказ T выводит таблицу по заданной температуре:

ввод:

```
T 20
```

вывод:

```
\/\/\/\   °C       K      °F   
  °C      20.00  293.15   68.00
   K    -253.15   20.00 -423.67
  °F      -6.67  266.48   20.00
```

А приказ C выводит только(!) перевод температуры из одной системы в другую:

ввод:

```
C 20 K F //Тобишь, 20 кельвинов в фарингейты
```

вывод:

```
20K =68F;
```

Суть проблемы - не понимаю как реализовать такую схему.
`if (scnaf(%c %lf %c %c, &a1 , &temp, &a2, &a3)==2)` не работает, сколько enter не нажимай он будет ждать пока я введу все 4 символа.

Строки и вообще что-то очень мудрое и сложное использовать нельзя, как быть?

Comment: читать по 1 символу? А не всё сразу.

Comment: суть задачи - ввести сразу все через пробел. Если считывать по одному символу, то только первый символ будет считываться и следующие scanf будут ожидать ввода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char cmd[2];
scanf("%1s", cmd);

if (*cmd == 'T')
  scanf("%lf", &t);
else
  scanf("%lf %c %c", &t, &from, &to);
```

Comment: Волшебство, все заработало!
Вот только, не понимаю, как это работает? Почему cmd а за ним квадртаные скобки и двойка?

Comment: @МитрофанШевцов, потому что массив из 2 элементов. Это я так от пробельных символов избавляюсь.